# Can I save an Image that I edited with Javascript, maybe using PHP, so that the change is permanent?

Tags: javascript, php, image

My overall goal is to let the user upload a picture, then preview it, then allow them to modify it, like any social media app lets you,

I have this in a (.php file) HTML document with JavaScript:

```
  <img src="uploads/profile24.jpeg" id="img">
  <label>blur</label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3" step="0.1" onchange="applyFilter()" data-filter = "blur" data-scale="px"> 


<script type="text/javascript">

        var image = document.getElementById('img');
        var filterControls = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
        function applyFilter(){

            var computedFilter = '';

            filterControls.forEach(function(item, index){

                computedFilter += item.getAttribute('data-filter') + '(' + item.value + item.getAttribute('data-scale') + ') ';

            });

            image.style.filter = computedFilter;


        }

</script>
```

What I want to do is make these changes permanent, so I can upload the edited Image with **PHP**, maybe overwrite the original.

Edit: I know I've said I'm also intrested in PHP libraries like GD, but I would like to exclude those answers for know, THANKS!

Comment: I want to thank anyone in advanced! This would really help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Imagick is a PHP extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick library.

Use below link as a example for permanent new image changes:

https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick